# Making button close a div for whole session

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some code, which shows a message when the browser window is sized to landscape mode. This works well, but now I want the user to be able to close the message with a button, and that the user only needs to do this once for the whole session. I guess you need sessionStorage for this but I do not know how to code this combined my existing code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[**AN EXAMPLE HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/4z9heaze/8/)

```
        Please open in "full page" mode and scale your window to a portrait size to see the message appear.
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="warning-message">
        <button type="button" id="landscape-button">X</button>
        <p><span id="headertext">please rotate your screen</span>
            <br>
            <br>This website is best viewed in landscape mode. So please, rotate your mobile device, and if activated also disable your screen rotation lock. If you prefer to remain in portrait mode, ignore this message and close it at the "x".</p>
    </div>



#warning-message {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    #warning-message {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media only screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    #warning-message {
        display: none;
    }
}

#warning-message {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    z-index: 99999999;
    background-color: #2A3847;
    width: 90vw;
    min-height: 90vh;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 15px 35px 15px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#landscape-button {
    background-color: #2A3847;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #ffffff;
    positie: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    "><span style="margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    letter-spacing: -0.04em;
}

#headertext {
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: -0.04em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#warning-message').on('click',function(){
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('isfirst');
if(data == undefined)
{
sessionStorage.setItem('isfirst', 'true');
//close the pop
}
})
```

Now each time check

```
sessionStorage.getItem('isfirst');
```

this will be stored thought the session

Comment: Thanks @Sameer, so I still need to add something at "//close the pop"? Could you code into the JS Fiddle example please please?

Comment: @eddy just use jquery.hide() to hide the element not a big deal :)

Comment: But where and how to I code this in, @sameer? As you can tell I am a code dummy :( Would you please be so kind to code it in for me so I can then learn from it? https://jsfiddle.net/4z9heaze/

Comment: please look here what I have so far, but what is not working: https://jsfiddle.net/4z9heaze/7/